# How to fix an error CS1061 in a C# console application?

Tags: c#, .net, unix, visual-studio-code

I am currently learning C# and .NET and I am currently learning how to make a NuGet package. One of the files that I have is set up as such:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

 namespace Packt.CS7
 {
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool IsValidXmlTag(this string input)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^<([a-z]+)([^<]+)*(?:>(.*)<\/\1>|\s+\/>)$");
    }

    public static bool IsValidPassword(this string input)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(input, "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{8,}$");
    }

    public static bool IsValidHex(this string input)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(input, "^#?([a-fA-F0-9]{3}|[a-fA-F0-9]{6})$");
    }
}
}
```

And my Program.cs is set up like this:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using static System.Console;
using Packt.CS7;

namespace Assemblies
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Write("Enter a valid color valid in hex: ");
        string hex = ReadLine();
        WriteLine($"Is {hex} a valid color value: {hex.IsValidHex()}");

        Write("Enter a valid XML tag: ");
        string xmlTag = ReadLine();
        WriteLine($"Is {xmlTag} a valid XML tag: {xmlTag.IsValidXmlTag()}");

        Write("Enter a valid password: ");
        string password = ReadLine();
        WriteLine($"Is {password} a valid password: {password.IsValidPassword()}");
    }
}
}
```

When the console application is run it is supposed to output:

```
Enter a valid color value in hex: 00ffc8
Is 00ffc8 a valid color value: True
Enter a valid XML tag: <h1 class="<" />
Is <h1 class="<" /> a valid XML tag: False
Enter a valid password: secretsauce
Is secretsauce a valid password: True
```

However what I am getting in the console is this:

```
Program.cs(14,60): error CS1061: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'IsValidHex' and no 
accessible extension method 'IsValidHex' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
[/Users/steelwind/HardWay/c#and.NET/Chapter07/Assemblies/Assemblies.csproj]

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.
```

I believe the problem lies in the fact when I open the first file, when it is open in VSCode it says that each of the classes has "0 references" meaning that it isn't being called somehow in the Program.cs. However I am not sure why.

Here is my files structure:

```
 Assemblies:
 >Assemblies.csproj
  ^bin
   ^Debug
    ^netcoreapp3.0
   ^Release
    ^netcoreapp3.0
     >Assemblies
    >Assemblies.deps.json
    >Assemblies.dll
    >Assemblies.pbd
    >Assemblies.runtimeconfig.dev.json
    >Assemblies.runtimeconfig.json
    >Newtonsoft.Json.dll
 ^obj
 >Program.cs

Shared library:
 ^bin
  ^Bin
   ^Debug
     ^netstandard2.0
      >SharedLibrary.deps.json
      >SharedLibrary.dll
      >SharedLibrary.pbd
     ^netstandard3.0
    wtsegarsMyFirstPackage1.0.0.nupkg
   ^Release
    ^netstandard
     >SharedLibrary.dll
     >SharedLibrary.pbd
 ^obj
 SharedLibrary.csproj
   StringExtensions.cs
```

Comment: Can you share the directory structure of your project ?

Comment: Are the two classes defined in the same project? If not, make sure your project containing Program.cs references the project that has your StringExtensions class.

Comment: Can you share the content of Assemblies.csproj ? Does it contains something like `<ProjectReference Include="..\Shared library\SharedLibrary.csproj" />` ?

Comment: @Kalten I just did but now it is showing up as an error that does not appear in the console only. Here is what it says:

Comment: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'IsValidHex' and no accessible extension method 'IsValidHex' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) [Assemblies]

Comment: Actually I was wrong, now I am getting this error:

Comment: /Users/steelwind/HardWay/c#and.NET/Chapter07/Assemblies/Assemblies.csproj(6,23): error MSB4066: The attribute "Include" in element <ProjectReference> is unrecognized.

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.

Comment: I got it to work I just had to move the project reference around a little bit and it worked

Answer (score 0):

It works (for me).

## A. Test

### Output

```
// .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0
Is 00ffc8 a valid color value: True
Is <h1 class="<" /> a valid XML tag: False
Is secretsauce a valid password: True
```

## B. What to do to debug

You could change `namespace Packt.CS7` to `namespace MyNewNamespace` and change `using Packt.CS7;` to `using MyNewNamespace;` and see if this compiles.

If you get `The type or namespace name 'Packt' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` it could mean that your app assembly is not referencing the necessary library/project.

## Test Code

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Packt.CS7;

namespace Packt.CS7
{
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static bool IsValidXmlTag(this string input)
         => Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^<([a-z]+)([^<]+)*(?:>(.*)<\/\1>|\s+\/>)$");

        public static bool IsValidPassword(this string input)
          => Regex.IsMatch(input, "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{8,}$");

        public static bool IsValidHex(this string input)
          => Regex.IsMatch(input, "^#?([a-fA-F0-9]{3}|[a-fA-F0-9]{6})$");
    }
}

namespace SixSixSix
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string hex = "00ffc8";
            Console.WriteLine($"Is {hex} a valid color value: {hex.IsValidHex()}");

            string xmlTag = @"<h1 class=""<"" />";
            Console.WriteLine($"Is {xmlTag} a valid XML tag: {xmlTag.IsValidXmlTag()}");

            string password = "secretsauce";
            Console.WriteLine($"Is {password} a valid password: {password.IsValidPassword()}");
        }
    }
}
```